# Why Mysqli prepare statement always returning false?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, slim

I have been trying to do a DELETE statement and i even tried running the query in MySQL workbench and everything was ok but in my service it does't seem to accept it.

```
      $statement_delete = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM crm_suite_tcl.aos_products_quotes where parent_id = ?");
       $statement_delete->bind_param("s", $id_pedido);

       $statement_delete->execute();
       $resultado_borrar_lineas = $statement_delete->get_result();
```

It throws that the statement is false, so it doesn't let me execute it 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp2\htdocs\crm\service\sync\include\db_handler.php on line 210
```

Comment: There's no result for a `DELETE` query. `$statement_delete->execute()` will return `true`, but there aren't any rows returned.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that it doesn't let me create the statement itself, it doesn't reach the `execute();` part, it just throws me a fatal error saying that `$statement_delete` is boolean.

Comment: You didn't think that was worth mentioning in the question?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, i'm just lost now

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting basically means that your statement cannot be prepared most likely due to a syntax error (a column or table that doesn't exist).

Try adding in your code:

```
if(!$statement_delete){
   error_log($this->conn->error);
}
```

This should write the error to the console and you will be able to correct it.

Comment: Please do not check manually for errors. OP is using a framework which already has a database class and a logger. You should avail of best practices instead of manually checking for errors after each line of code.